# using editText Globally

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, global

I'm new in android developing. in my simple project I'm using an editText very often to get the value in my java file and I wanted to declare and find my edit text just one time and after that i Use it in my entire java file. I code like this:

```
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);


public void onClick1(View v){
    Editable input = editText.getText();
    this.editText.setText(input+"1");

}
public void onClick2(View v){
    Editable input = editText.getText();
    this.editText.setText(input+"2");

}
```

but this code close my application unexpectedly when I try to run it.
Please let me know your idea about declaring that edit text and using in my functions.

Comment: Can you please provide stacktrace please?

Comment: where can i find it? @JoãoElvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define`EditText editText;` right after your class declaration (`private` is suggested), so, it should look like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
     private EditText editText;
     ...
}
```

and initialize in your `onCreate()` method

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

So you can reach that throughtout your class